# Adding new rows to a dataframe for every individual ID

Tags: r

I have a df with rows relating to an individual survey. If an animal was spotted during the survey, details of the location were also included. I want to add rows for every location per survey, whether or not there was a sighting. I have 5 locations (A,B,C,D,E).

For example, my data currently looks like this:

[image]

And I want it to look like this:

[image]

This is just an example df, my actual df is very large

Comment: Welcome to SO, JaneSmith! Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly into a [code block].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it could be a "full join" after an `expand`.

Try:

```r
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(Date = Sys.Date() + 1:5, Location=c("A", NA, "A", "B", NA), Num = 1:5)
df1
#         Date Location Num
# 1 2024-01-11        A   1
# 2 2024-01-12     <NA>   2
# 3 2024-01-13        A   3
# 4 2024-01-14        B   4
# 5 2024-01-15     <NA>   5

expand(df1, Date, Location=LETTERS[1:5]) %>%
  full_join(df1, by=c("Date", "Location")) %>%
  print(n=99)
# # A tibble: 27 × 3
#    Date       Location   Num
#    <date>     <chr>    <int>
#  1 2024-01-11 A            1
#  2 2024-01-11 B           NA
#  3 2024-01-11 C           NA
#  4 2024-01-11 D           NA
#  5 2024-01-11 E           NA
#  6 2024-01-12 A           NA
#  7 2024-01-12 B           NA
#  8 2024-01-12 C           NA
#  9 2024-01-12 D           NA
# 10 2024-01-12 E           NA
# 11 2024-01-13 A            3
# 12 2024-01-13 B           NA
# 13 2024-01-13 C           NA
# 14 2024-01-13 D           NA
# 15 2024-01-13 E           NA
# 16 2024-01-14 A           NA
# 17 2024-01-14 B            4
# 18 2024-01-14 C           NA
# 19 2024-01-14 D           NA
# 20 2024-01-14 E           NA
# 21 2024-01-15 A           NA
# 22 2024-01-15 B           NA
# 23 2024-01-15 C           NA
# 24 2024-01-15 D           NA
# 25 2024-01-15 E           NA
# 26 2024-01-12 NA           2
# 27 2024-01-15 NA           5
```

(The `print(n=99)` is just to show the whole frame in this answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Do `expand.grid` `with` ranges and unique values of some variables of your data, then `merge` with it using `all=TRUE`. Make sure that variables are of same type (e.g. date, character, numeric, ...) and have identical names.

```
> egrid <- with(dat, 
+      expand.grid(
+        date=as.Date(min(date):max(date)),
+        id=min(id):max(id),
+        location=LETTERS[1:5]
+        )
+ )
> res <- merge(egrid, dat[rowSums(is.na(dat[, 3:5])) == 0, ], all=TRUE)
> res$sighting[is.na(res$sighting)] <- 'N'  ## if needed
> res
          date id location sighting  time
1   2015-01-01  1        A        Y 10:15
2   2015-01-01  1        B        N  <NA>
3   2015-01-01  1        C        N  <NA>
4   2015-01-01  1        D        N  <NA>
5   2015-01-01  1        E        N  <NA>
6   2015-01-01  2        A        N  <NA>
...
61  2015-01-03  3        A        Y 10:01
62  2015-01-03  3        B        Y 12:51
64  2015-01-03  3        D        N  <NA>
...
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(date = structure(c(16436, 16437, 16438, 16438, 
16439, 16440), class = "Date"), id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L
), sighting = c("Y", NA, "Y", "Y", NA, NA), time = c("10:15", 
NA, "10:01", "12:51", NA, NA), location = c("A", NA, "A", "B", 
NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```